# Arreglo dentro de un Foreach me sustituye valores obtenidos de una consulta SQL

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de recoger numeros de cuenta que ingresa el usuario mediante un textarea y verificar si existe o no en la base de datos.

El arreglo `$nuevoArreglo` contiene cada elemento que envio el usuario desde el textarea.

Luego dentro del `for()` convierto los elementos dentro del arreglo `$nuevoArreglo` en enteros (int). Luego, realizo la consulta SQL y vienen los siguientes problemas:

1. Con un solo numero de cuenta que no exista en la base de datos, si muestra mediante un `var_dump($G300)` que no existe en la base de datos, devuelve **empty**. Los problemas resultan cuando hay mas de un numero de cuenta que envia el usuario (exista o no en la base de datos), si los numeros de cuenta existen en la BD, los numeros de cuenta se almacenan en el arreglo y sustituyen o reemplazan (no lo se con claridad) a los numeros de cuenta que no existen en la tabla.
2. Si ingreso un numero de cuenta que exista, luego uno que no exista, y luego otro que si exista en la BD. El arreglo donde se almacenan, solo reigstrar los elementos que si existan en la BD.

***Lo que quiero obtener son los numeros de cuenta que no existen en la base de datos.***

```
    $mult = $_POST['numCuenta'];

    #VARIABLES
    $datos = array();  $nuevoArreglo = array(); $G300 = array();

    #LA VARIABLE $datos CONTIENE CADA ELEMENTO ENVIADO DESDE EL TEXTAREA, SIN ESPACIOS AL INICIO Y AL FINAL DE CADA ELEMENTO
    $datos =  explode("\n", trim($mult)); 

    #EL CICLO FOREACH RECORRE CADA UNO DE LOS ELEMENTOS DEL ARREGLO $datos Y LUEGO SE LE ASIGNA A OTRO ARREGLO ($nuevoArreglo)
    foreach($datos as $dato){
        $nuevoArreglo[] = $dato;
    };

    $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=192.168.1.95:1521/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'bi_src', 'bi_src');

for($i = 0; $i < count($nuevoArreglo); $i++){
            $nuevoArreglo[$i] = (int) trim($nuevoArreglo[$i]);

            $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = $nuevoArreglo[$i]");
            $stid->execute();

            foreach($stid as $row){
                $G300[] = $row['G300CTA'];
            }

        };
    var_dump($G300);
```

**Codigo actual**

```
if ( !$mult ) {
        header("refresh:4;url=index.php");
        $errores = "<p><i class='fas fa-times-circle'></i> Por favor ingrese los datos correctamente</p>";
    } else {
        #VARIABLES
        $G300 = array(); $noExisten = array(); $M000 = array(); $noMarcaje = array(); 
        $datos = explode("\n", trim($mult)); 

        $n = count($datos);

        /*CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS*/
        $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=192.168.1.95:1521/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'bi_src', 'bi_src');

        /*VERIFICAR SI UNA CUENTA INGRESADA EXISTE O NO EN LA GSCF300*/
        foreach($datos as $row ){
            $cuenta=(int) $row ;
            $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = ?");

            if ( $stid && $stid->execute( array($cuenta) ) ) {
                $total=$stid->fetchColumn();
                if( $total>0 ) {
                    $G300[] = $cuenta;
                } else {
                    $noExisten[] = $cuenta;
                }
                $stid->closeCursor();
            } else {
                echo "Error en la consulta: ". $stid->errorInfo()[2];
            }
        }

        // var_dump($G300);
        // var_dump($noExisten);

        // SI EXISTEN EN LA TABLA GSCF300
        if(!empty($G300)){
            /*COMPROBAR SI EXISTE O NO EN LA TABLA DE MARCAJE*/
            foreach($G300 as $row){
                $cuenta=(int) $row;
            //EL ERROR SUCEDE AQUI, AL REALIZAR LA CONSULTA SQL, SIEMPRE 
            //DEVUELVE 0, EXISTA O NO, EN LA BD SI EXISTE, ME DEVUELVE 1
               $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 WHERE G300CTA = ?");
                if ($stid && $stid->execute(array($cuenta))){
                    $total=$stid->fetchColumn();

                    if( $total > 0 ) {
                        /*si existe se almacena aqui*/
                        $M000[] = $cuenta;
                    } else {
                        /*si no existe se almacena aqui*/
                        $noMarcaje[] = $cuenta;
                    }
                    $stid->closeCursor();
                } else {
                    echo "Error en la consulta: ". $stid->errorInfo()[2];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Víctor, estás cayendo en algunos errores de una pregunta anterior.

- No consultas preparadas (fallo de seguridad)
- No uso de `fetch` para moverte entre los resultados
- No control del dato pasado por POST
- No cierre del cursor de `$stdi`

A eso le sumamos que la lógica que estás usando es errada, a veces redundante en varios puntos:

1. Dices que quieres guardar los que no existen, pero de hecho no los guardas en ningún momento
2. En `$nuevoArreglo` creas un array que de hecho ya existe, porque `$datos` es un array que se crea con `explode`
3. No hace falta más `trim` sobre el dato, ya lo hiciste en el `explode`

Hay más cosas que se me escapan ahora y que he corregido en mi propuesta de código.

Aquí te la dejo, prueba y dime cómo te va. Aquí voy llenando dos arrays, uno cuando existe y otro cuando no existe. Luego usarás el que necesites.

Espero te sirva.

```
<?php 

    $mult = ( !empty($_POST['numCuenta']) ) ? $_POST['numCuenta'] : NULL;

    if ( !$mult ) {
         echo "No hay datos en el POST";    
    } else {
        #VARIABLES
        $G300 = array(); 
        $noExisten = array();
        $datos =  explode("\n", trim($mult)); 

        $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=192.168.1.95:1521/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'bi_src', 'bi_src');

        foreach( $datos as $row ){
            $cuenta=(int) $row ;
            $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = ?");
            if ( $stid && $stid->execute( array($cuenta) ) ) {
                $total=$stid->fetchColumn();
                if( $total>0 ) {
                    $G300[] = $cuenta;
                } else {
                    $noExisten[]=$cuenta;
                }
                $stid->closeCursor();
            } else {
                echo "Error en la consulta: ". $stid->errorInfo()[2];
            }

        }
    }
    # Prueba de los dos arrays obtenidos
    var_dump($G300);
    var_dump($noExisten);

?>
```

Comment: Implemente el codigo que dejaste y sucede lo siguiente, los datos enviados se almacenan en el arreglo `$noExisten` , existan o no existan, todo se almacena ahi, respecto al arreglo `$G300`no almacena nada, siempre devuelve **empty**

Comment: @VíctorÁlvarez ¿podrías mostrarme el resultado de ambos `var_dump`?

Comment: **var_dump($G300)** : array (size=0)
  empty **var_dump($noExisten)**: array (size=3)
  0 => int 1106001330
  1 => int 1104026222
  2 => int 1104012172  **Todos los numeros ingresados existen en la BD**

Comment: Ok, por ejemplo, ¿si ejecutas esto en la BD directamente arroja datos?: **`SELECT G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = 1106001330;`** No me digas que sí, pruébalo en la BD directamente.

Comment: Ya lo probe en la BD y si arroja datos, me devuelve el mismo numero consultado (1106001330)

Comment: Ok, puede ser un problema con `rowCount()` ... espera...

Comment: A ver @VíctorÁlvarez, he cambiado un poco la lógica. Si se trata de verificar que la cuenta existe, es mejor usar un `COUNT` y luego verificar la cantidad de filas que trajo la consulta. Ahí no tiene sentido un `foreach` interno para meter en el array los datos que haya traído. A lo sumo, si quieres saber cuántas veces está esa cuenta puedes usar el valor de `$total`. Revisa la respuesta editada y prueba, creo que así funcionará y es más lógico.

Comment: Excelente, ahora si funciona y separa los que existen y los que no, muchas gracias, estoy agradecido totalmente

Comment: Me alegro @VíctorÁlvarez y no retrocedas en el código. En otra pregunta llegamos a un código seguro y aplicando buenas prácticas, cuando vi esta pregunta vi que habías vuelto a dejar de usar consultas preparadas y otras técnicas. Hacer eso en un entorno de producción puede ser muy grave. Saludos.

Comment: Otra duda, como se podria realizar traer otro parametro de la consulta? **por ejemplo:** `SELECT count(*), G300NCTL FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = ? GROUP BY G300NCTL`

Comment: @VíctorÁlvarez para poder responder a esa duda habría que conocer más sobre  la estructura de la tabla. Aquí se trata de agrupar los datos y este tipo de consultas requiere un conocimiento de la composición de las tablas (si es que quieres una consulta que cumpla con el estándar SQL). MySQL es muy permisivo agrupando datos y arroja resultados en consultas que están mal agrupadas, pero no es bueno ampararse en esa permisividad. Para evitarlo, pon eso siempre antes de cualquier consulta con GROUP BY: `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`Creo que es mejor que plantees tu duda en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar que si el $row['G300CTA'] este vacio no inserte en el arreglo los valores, tambien usa el [array_push](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) para que no sustituyas los valores del arreglo, este lo que hace es insertar los valores al final del arreglo

```
foreach($stid as $row){
    if(isset($row['G300CTA'])){
        array_push($G300, $row['G300CTA']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo hice de esta informa y sigue sustituyendo los valroes dentro del array

Comment: Que es lo que te devuelve el $stid? podrías darle un var_dump antes del foreach y anexar el resultado?

Comment: Esto es lo que devuelve el **var_dump**: object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = 1104026222' (length=61)
C:\wamp64\www\Practicas\mult.php:29:
object(PDOStatement)[3]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = 1104012172' (length=61)

Comment: Creo que no esta ejecutando la consulta, por que te esta devolviendo los querys y no el resultado de los mismos, si te fijas en este ejemplo que replique, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a1bbc4203f40b334129a0e0c0110479f50e37594 si funciona, y no reemplaza los valores del array, analizando el var_dump que muestras, debería regresarte los valores de GC300CTA, cierto?

Comment: Si, pero solo devuelve los valores que existen en la base de datos, no muestra ni siquiera los que no existen, si voy a la BD y hago el mismo SQL, me devuelve empty pero en php no lo almacena los que no existen